# SlickNav: How to make the menu close up after clicking on it

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, menu

I need to make a slicknav menu in a fixed header, that goes up after clicking on a link.
So far i am arrived at this point: http://jsbin.com/UqUloNO/5

There is the slicknav menu in a fixed header.
Now the problem is that the menu don't close up after clicking on a link, as it should be, and how you can see in the homepage of the plugin: http://slicknav.com/  (if you resize the browser will appear the mobile-menu slicknav)

What can i do to make it close-up after clicking?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `closeOnClick:true`  to close

```
$(function(){
      $('#menu').slicknav({
        closeOnClick:true
      });
    });
```

http://jsbin.com/UqUloNO/6/

Comment: Thank you Manish! Can i ask something little: do you have seen a little noise right after clicking on the menu?
Do you know perhaps how can i resolve that?

Comment: I have added z-index: 999; and it is a bit better:  http://jsbin.com/UqUloNO/7/edit
Though there is still a little blink right after clicking.
DO you have perhaps better solutions?

Comment: @johnnyfittizio It will automatically remove when your slide down to div on menu click starts working . Will inform u if i find any solution

Answer (score 0):

slicknav menu onclick on outside of menu close not working

```
$(function(){
      $('#menu2').slicknav({
        closeOnClick:true
      });
    });

<script>$('#menu2').slicknav({
        label: 'Main Menu',
        duration: 1000,
        easingOpen: "easeOutBounce",
        prependTo:'#mainmenu'
    });</script>
```